# Join/append multiple, identical polygon layers into a single layer whilst retaining all attributes?

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-plugins

I have run some analysis (zonalstats) on different raster layers using the same analysis polygons. I want to concatenate all these different layers together, i.e. retain a single polygon and have a "wide" table of attributes for each one (needs to be a batch process rather than one layer at a time).

The attributes have the same name (e.g. `max`, `min`, `average`) so there would need to be a way to identify which polygon layer they came from when creating the merged table. I could just go into the dbf file and copy and paste into a spreadsheet as the analysis polygons are identical but this doesn't seem very elegant and I am hoping to do this with larger datasets.